# Adding a value to a template from a variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a variable test

```yaml
test:
 - 10.0.0.1
 - 10.0.0.2
 - 10.0.0.3
 - 10.0.0.4
```

And there is a config file where you need to insert one value from this variable. There should be 4 config files in the output, each file contains one line from this test variable. I figured out how to make 4 files be created with ip names from the list, but I can't understand how to make ip substituted into the template.

From template:

```
auto br_omgt
iface br_omgt inet static
bridge_ports bond0.2210
 address {{ db }}
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  gateway 10.15.35.62
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [module template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html).
Your file must be jinja2.

role/MY_Role/templates/my_file.txt.j2

```
my_file.txt.j2
auto br_omgt iface br_omgt inet static bridge_ports bond0.2210 address {{ db }} netmask 255.255.255.192 gateway 10.15.35.62


my_file.txt  
auto br_omgt iface br_omgt inet static bridge_ports bond0.2210 address 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.192 gateway 10.15.35.62
```

Playbook :

```
  vars:
    db: 10.0.0.1

  tasks:
  - name: Use Template
    template:
      src: my_file.txt.j2
      dest: home/My_User/my_file.txt
```

With a loop, you got 4 files. ( [Extended](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) )

```
  vars:
    db: 10.0.0.1
        10.0.0.2

  tasks:
  - name: Use Template looped
    template:
      src: my_file.txt.j2
      dest: home/My_User/my_file_{{index}}.txt
    loop_control:
      extended: yes
    loop: "{{ db }}"
```